# How to acquire fully qualified names of installed applications in Android

Tags: android, fully-qualified-naming

I try to create an application that can start other applications (f.e. Gmail or Facebook or any installed one).

I tried to use the following code:

```
PackageManager pm = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
try
{
  Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("FULLY QUALIFIED NAME");
  if (it != null)
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(it);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{ }
```

However, it requires the fully qualified name of the application.

How can I acquire it? Is there any built-in method to get them?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better simply to find the launchable activities, the way home screen launchers do?

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application may have zero, one, or several activities that belong in a launcher. Hence, a launcher should not be asking "what are all the applications, and what is the launch `Intent` for each?" A launcher should, instead, be asking "what are all of the activities that I should show?"

That is accomplished using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) implements a complete launcher. The key lines are:

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
```

Then, you can use whatever mechanism you want to render that `launchables` collection. The sample project puts them in a `ListView`.

Comment: Great explanation, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a List of all applications like this:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Now you've stored all applications with their meta data in a `List`. You can get their package name like this:

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

Comment: Good to know these things, too.